# Jquery add all screen span attribute with text

Tags: jquery, attributes

I want to get all span text an add a input attribute on my screen, something like this

```
$('span').attr('test', this.text);
```

but the `this.text` was not working, how can I get the span text on this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.attr(attributeName, fn)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function)

```
$('span').attr('test', function() { 
  return this.textContent;
});
```

However I would recommend you to use `data-*` prefixed custom attribute

```
$('span').attr('data-test', function() { 
  return this.textContent;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('span').each(function() { 
  $(this).attr('test', $(this).text());
});
```

Comment: I trying to do this without each, but i'm afraid that isn't possible =/